# How do you set the height of a Vaadin 8 Grid to be undefined?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I've tried both `Grid.setUndefined()` and `Grid.setHeight("-1px")` and neither works. They should both be doing the same but if my grid only has say 3 items then the bottom of the grid is empty and the height is significantly taller than 3 rows.

Comment: Are you adding Grid component with expanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `setHeightByRows` method ([Java doc](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.2/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html#setHeightByRows-double-)).

Comment: That's exactly what I did but the last row was a bit truncated. However it's good enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposition for workaround:

```java
grid.getDataProvider().addDataProviderListener( dataProviderEvent ->
                grid.setHeightByRows( grid.getDataProvider().size( new Query() ) ) 
);
```

Comment: Your solution work great, But you should check the size of your datas. It should be more than zero rows, otherwise it will return error.

Answer (score 1):

Set the grid HeightMode to UNDEFINED:

```
grid.setHeightMode(HeightMode.UNDEFINED);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.